# Incorrect result of FourierTransform

Tags: bugs, integral-transforms

Let us consider in 13.2 on Windows 10

```
FourierTransform[1/Sinh[x]^2, x, k]
```

> `-((2 + k \[Pi] Coth[(k \[Pi])/2])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])`

This is not a usual Fourier transform beacause of a non-integrable singularity at the origin

```
Series[1/Sinh[x]^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> 1/x^2-1/3+x^2/15+O[x]^3

Neither [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) nor Kammler, David (2000), A First Course in Fourier Analysis,
Prentice Hall, ISBN 978-0-13-578782-3 contain this formula (BTW, the "Fourier transform" as well as "Homosexuality" articles
in English Wiki are permanently edited.).

Next, let us return to the original function by

```
InverseFourierTransform[-((2 + k \[Pi] Coth[(k \[Pi])/2])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]), k, x] // FullSimplify
```

> `Csch[x]^2 - 2 DiracDelta[x]`

As we see, the fundamental property of the Fourier transform `InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t], t, \[Omega]], \[Omega], t]==f[t]` does not hold in this case. Is it a bug or I don't understand something?

Comment: @bmf I can recover OP's result. For this one `InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t], t, ω], ω, t]==f[t]` I think MMA just stores this property for symbolics.

Comment: @yurie I was being blind to something in my notebook...

Comment: There shouldn't be the constant term. Since `Coth`'s Fourier transform is `Coth`, and we take derivative getting `1/Sinh[x]^2`, then in the momentum space we get `k Coth[k]`.

Answer (score 4):

I have no explanation for the problematic transform. I will show instead a way to get the correct one.

We treat this as `1/x^2 * x^2/Sinh[x]^2`. We take the Fourier transform as the convolution of the separate transforms for `1/x^2` and `x^2/Sinh[x]^2`. We handle that latter using `Integrate` directly.

```
ftoneoverx2 = FourierTransform[1/x^2, x, k]

(* Out[648]= -k Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Sign[k] *)

ftx2overSinhx2 = 
 1/(2*Pi)*
  Integrate[Exp[-I*k*x]*x^2/Sinh[x]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {Element[k, Reals], e > 0}]

(* Out[649]= (\[Pi] (-2 + k \[Pi] Coth[(k \[Pi])/2]))/(2 (-1 + 
   Cosh[k \[Pi]])) *)
```

Convolve these.

```
ft = 
 Simplify[
  Integrate[
   ftx2overSinhx2*(ftoneoverx2 /. k -> t - k), {k, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]]

(* Out[650]= -(((1 + E^(\[Pi] t)) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] t)/(-1 + E^(\[Pi] t))) *)
```

Check that we recover the original function on taking the inverse transform.

```
ift = InverseFourierTransform[ft, t, x]

(* Out[651]= Csch[x]^2 *)
```

--- edit ---

I was asked about verifying some of these. `ftoneoverx2` is, up to constant factor dependent on parameter settings, well known. It's in an appendix in the book by Kammler for example. Here is a numerical check for the next part.

```
ftx2overSinhx2 /. k -> {-1.4, 3.7}
{1/(2*Pi)*
  NIntegrate[Exp[-I*(-1.4)*x]*x^2/Sinh[x]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}],
 1/(2*Pi)*
  NIntegrate[Exp[-I*(3.7)*x]*x^2/Sinh[x]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]}

(* Out[98]= {0.0993251, 0.000270598}

Out[99]= {0.0993251 + 0. I, 0.000270598 + 0. I} *)
```

We can check `ft` in the same way.

```
ft /. t -> {-1.4, 3.7}
{NIntegrate[
  ftx2overSinhx2*(ftoneoverx2 /. k -> -1.4 - k), {k, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}], 
 NIntegrate[
  ftx2overSinhx2*(ftoneoverx2 /. k -> 3.7 - k), {k, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}]}

(* Out[101]= {-1.79834, -4.63735}

Out[102]= {-1.79834, -4.63735} *)
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: I am out of MMA so  I ' ll respond later.

Comment: Thank you for your work. I can reproduce it in both 13.1 and 13.2. However, this generates more questions: (i) `Convolve[ftoneoverx2, ftx2overSinh2, k, t]` produces ``(1/(6 (-1 + E^(\[Pi] t)) Sqrt[
 2 \[Pi]]))(12 I \[Pi] - 12 I E^(\[Pi] t) \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]^2 + 
  2 E^(\[Pi] t) \[Pi]^2 - 6 \[Pi] t - 6 E^(\[Pi] t) \[Pi] t + 
  12 I \[Pi]^2 t - 12 I E^(\[Pi] t) \[Pi]^2 t + 
  6 \[Pi] t Log[1/(1 - E^(\[Pi] t))] - 
  6 E^(\[Pi] t) \[Pi] t Log[1/(1 - E^(\[Pi] t))] - 
  6 Log[1/(1 - E^(\[Pi] t))] Log[-1 +...
  6 (-1 + E^(\[Pi] t)) PolyLog[2, E^(\[Pi] t)/(-1 + E^(\[Pi] t))])` , not your result.

Comment: While I agree that `Convolve` seems likely to do what you intend, I'm not familiar with it's design or implementation.

Comment: (ii)`FourierTransform[x^2/Sinh[x]^2, x, k]` produces `(-2 \[Pi]^2 Csch[(k \[Pi])/2]^2 + 
 k \[Pi]^3 Coth[(k \[Pi])/2] Csch[(k \[Pi])/2]^2)/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])`,. not `ftx2overSinh2`. (iii) Formula 310 in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) is given without any reference so it is not reliable .

Comment: I was aware FT did not correctly handle `x^2/Sinh[x]^2`. That's why I used `Integrate`.

Comment: Did you check the results of `ftx2overSinh2` and `ft` numerically?

Comment: How about `ftoneoverx2`?

Comment: The FT for 1/x^2 looked plausible, and I recovered the function from the inversing so I assume the other was also viable.

Comment: "The FT for 1/x^2 looked plausible" -  I prefer arguments over emotional words.  Many results of integral transforms are implemented in CASes as table values. Your answer would be more solid if the one was confirmed numerically.

Comment: BTW, `FourierTransform[-(((1 + E^(\[Pi] t)) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] t)/(-1 + 
      E^(\[Pi] t))), t, s]` also  produces `Csch[s]^2` in 13.2 on Windows.

Comment: The same output in 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: You are welcome to test them. I doubt I’ll have a chance for a while.